# Vue - How to override all: unset for inner components

Tags: css, vue.js

I'm injecting Vue app in to existing webpage which can be any page.

And I'm using this scss

```
#vueApp {
 all: unset
  * {
   all: unset
  }
}
```

on my Vue root element, to remove all parent styles from existing webpage to be applied in my Vue app.

But it also removes my styles I'm using in my own components.

I want my styles to be applied ON TOP of the applied **all: unset** style.

As I understand it happens because

```
#vauApp * {all: unset}
```

have higher priority than my components styles because it have deeper selector. And my component styles have only one selector for example

```
.myButton {...}
```

**Current solution**
Add additional selector to components styles

```
<style lang="scss" scoped>
  #vueApp .myButton {
  ...
  }
```

Comment: What does existing webpage mean in this context, like are injecting it into the same Vue project and by page you mean view?

Comment: @Dejan.S existing webpage is ANY webpage in the inernet not controlled by me.

Comment: Ok so you are doing components so anybody could use as npm packages? Like a button or? It's still unclear of the context what the usage is and what you actually are building. Clearing that out will help to give you the right solution.

Comment: @Dejan.S its a browser extension.